# How to use Jquery form plugin-in ASP.NET Webform?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I came across this plug in: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

I was wondering how can I use this in asp.net webforms? 
What do I replace  `action="comment.php"` with? Webmethod?

**ASPX:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('frmMaster').ajaxForm(function () {
            alert("Thank you for your comment!");
        });
    }); 
</script>

     <form id="myForm" action="Default.aspx/UPLOAD" method="post"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>
 </asp:Content>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
[WebMethod]
    public string UPLOAD(HttpContext context)
    {

        return "test";
    }
```

NOTE: I am using masterpage.

Comment: did you get the solution