# Is it possible to send entire form including the files to server using jquery/ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Is it possible to submit entire form (all the fields including fileupload) to server (webmethod or handler etc) using Jquery/Ajax?  If yes, how?

**ASPX:**

```
$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "SupplierBidding.aspx/SubmitBid",
               data: JSON.stringify({ id: $('#txtbidderid').val(), bidamt: $('#txtbidamt').val() }),
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               async: true,
               success: function (data, status) {
                   span.fadeIn("slow", function () {
                       span.text(data.d).fadeOut('slow');
                   });             
               },
               failure: function (data) {
                   alert(data.d);                  
               },
               error: function (data) {
                   alert(data.d);
                   setTimeout(function () {
                       btn.prop('disabled', false);
                   }, 3000);
               }
           });
       }
```

**WebMethod:**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string SubmitBid(string id, string bidamt)
    {
     //code
return "";

    }
```

I would like to replace `data: JSON.stringify({ id: $('#txtbidderid').val(), bidamt: $('#txtbidamt').val() })`  with entire form including files also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Formdata`.

**[FormData Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)**

Code example.

```
var fdata = new FormData();    
fdata.append( 'file', input.files[0] );

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://yourserver.com/upload.php',
  data: fdata,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    console.log('siceess')
  }
});
```

Comment: what would do i replace upload.php' with in asp.net? Name of webmethod? Or handler name?

Comment: i don't know have to do that in asp.net in backend.

Comment: That is exactly where i have been stuck for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try jQuery Form plugin?
It handles [file uploads](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload).
Worked for me before.

Comment: May be you can asnwer one of my earlier questions :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409448/how-to-use-jquery-form-plugin-in-asp-net-webform